# centered vertical lines between borders

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a checkout/thankyouforyourorder page for a webshop, and i made different borders with text in them explaining the process after you succesfully placed an order. I gave my borders an orange color and have 4 of them in a row under each other. I want an orange line in the center of them all so i can link them together and style them so i can make a chronologic process of how their order arrives at home. I hope this makes sense, because i have no clue of how to explain it any other way and i can't wrap my head around where i have to look or what to look for. Can anyone who understands this help me?

```
.opsomming {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 3;
    border-color: #FFA500;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px ##3F3F3F;
    font-family: Georgia, Times;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #FFBA43;
}
```

this is 1 of the borders, what i want to do is make a vertical line in the middle of them all, so i can link them together.

Comment: How do you mean code? like this? 
.opsomming {
    width:600px;
    border: 1px ;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 3;
    border-color: #FFA500;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px ##3F3F3F;
    font-family: Georgia, Times;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #FFBA43;
}
 this is 1 of the borders, what i want to do is make a vertical line in the middle of them all, so i can link them together.

Comment: infuse this in u question

Comment: add the image as it should work

Comment: Please show us your code or create a fiddle, where we can reproduce your issue and see your research effort. Unless you do, we can only guess. --- Please see the help on how to post good questions!

Comment: Or can you just show us a little image of how it should look like. We (or at least I) cannot grasp what you actually are trying to achieve and what you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

[image: Prosess test]

HTML

```
<div class="leftline-wrap">
  <div class="opsomming">content</div>
  <div class="opsomming">content</div>
  <div class="opsomming">content</div>
  <div class="opsomming">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.opsomming {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 3;
    border-color: #FFA500;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3F3F3F;
    font-family: Georgia, Times;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #FFBA43;
}
.opsomming {
    margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:5px;max-width: 90%;position:relative;
}
.opsomming:before { 
    display:block;
    content: "";
    border-top: 1px solid #FFA500;
    width:10px;
    height:1px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    top:45%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left:-1px;
}
.leftline-wrap {
    border-left: 1px solid #FFA500; 
}
```

(1)   https://jsfiddle.net/q6xzxoan/2/

or like this

[image]

(2)   https://jsfiddle.net/9ua89hds/4/